# How to disable a script which is attached to random characters in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, random, char

I've been developing a game but there is something that I can't figure out because of being a little bit new in the language and the editor. I create some random characters that have a basic movement script. Yet I also use collision for making them stop when they touch something. So the problem occurs at this point. I should get all the characters in an array and then I should use a loop as far as I know but I cannot do that because I have a generator and I don't know the numbers of the characters and I can't add them as a component to main script.

So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all why can't the generator keep track of the generated characters in a List? You could make this List public and would easily have access to them. Something like e.g.

```
public List<THE_TYPE>() Characters = new List<THE_TYPE>();

void GenerateCharacter()
{
    // now everytime you generate a new character add it to the list e.g.
    var newChar = Instantiate(...);

    Characters.Add(newChar.GetComponent<THE_TYPE>());
}
```

you then could simply use that list, filter the null entries (objects that might have been destroyed already) and disabled components out, pick a random entry, disable its component and remove it from the list like

```
using System.Linq;

...

referenceToGenerator.Characters = referenceToGenerator.Characters.Where(c => c != null && c.enabled = true).ToList();

var pickedCharacter = referenceToGenerator.Characters[Random.Range(0, referenceToGenerator.Characters.Count)];
pickedCharacter.enabled = false;
// or if you rather wanted to deactivate the GameObject
//pickedCharacter.gameObject.SetActive(false);
referenceToGenerator.Characters.Remove(pickedCharacter);
```

---

In general: If they all have a certain component attached you could also simply use [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) which anyway finds only active and enabled components to get an array of all instances in the scene ... then just pick a random entry and disable the according element

```
var instances = FindObjectsOfType<THETYPE>(); 
instance[Random.Range(0, instances.Length)].enabled = false;
```

or if you rather wanted to deactivate the entire GameObject

```
instance[Random.Range(0, instances.Length)].gameObject.SetActive(false);
```

if possible though you should tray to rather store them in a List somewhere since `FindObjectsOfType` is of course a bit performance intense.